# Not receiving data from outside of a async forEach

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I was doing this function on a React Native app, when I tried to return some data that i got from axios.get, but outside of forEach, it is empty, while inside it, it has the data. How could I fix this?

```js
async function search(){
    try{
        var url = 'http://localhost:3002/categorias'
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        var categorias = response.data
        var catRandom = []
        var i = 5
        while(i--){
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * categorias.length)
            catRandom.push(categorias[j]["id"])
            categorias.splice(j, 1)
        }
        var ret = []
        await catRandom.forEach(async (element) => {
            var url = 'http://localhost:3002/textos/categoria/' + element
            const response = await axios.get(url);
            var dado = response.data
            ret.push(dado)
            console.log(ret)  // returns data, fine
        });
        console.log(ret)  // returns "[]", empty
        return ret
    }
    catch(error){
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how `categorias` should look like if console.logged?

Comment: @AlphaHowl it is a number array, like "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.forEach` [returns undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value) so even if there is an await in front of it, it won't await for all the async callbacks to be complete.
The second log that prints an empty array happens before the ones inside the `forEach` callbacks.

If you don't mind all requests happening in parallel, you could use `.map` instead.It will return an array of promises that will resolve with whatever gets returned inside the callback.

```
    const promArr = catRandom.map(async (element) => {
        const url = 'http://localhost:3002/textos/categoria/' + element;
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        const dado = response.data
        return dado;
    });
    const res = await Promise.all(promArr);
    return res;
```

I've used `Promise.all` to be able to wait for all the promises to be fulfilled. [Promise.all docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 0):

As @user16708140 stated in their answer, you can use `Promise.all` to achieve the desired result. However if you insist on using a loop, you can use async `for loops` like this: Here I've included the bare minimum code required to be usable in your case:

```js
async function get(url){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("Got data from " + url), 750);
    });
};

async function search() {
    const my_array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const x = await get("Your-url-" + i);
        my_array.push(x);
        console.log(x);
    };
    console.log("\nHere is the array: ");
    console.log(my_array);
};

search();
```